# MongoDB filter for specific data in Array and return only specific fields in the output

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a below structure maintained in a sample collection.

```
{
  "_id": "1",
  "name": "Stock1",
  "description": "Test Stock",
  "lines": [
    {
      "lineNumber": "1",
      "priceInfo": {
        "buyprice": 10,
        "sellprice": 15
      },
      "item": {
        "id": "BAT10001",
        "name": "CricketBat",
        "description": "Cricket bat"
      },
      "quantity": 10
    },
    {
      "lineNumber": "2",
      "priceInfo": {
        "buyprice": 10,
        "sellprice": 15
      },
      "item": {
        "id": "BAT10002",
        "name": "CricketBall",
        "description": "Cricket ball"
      },
      "quantity": 10
    },
    {
      "lineNumber": "3",
      "priceInfo": {
        "buyprice": 10,
        "sellprice": 15
      },
      "item": {
        "id": "BAT10003",
        "name": "CricketStumps",
        "description": "Cricket stumps"
      },
      "quantity": 10
    }
  ]
}
```

I have a scenario where i will be given `lineNumber` and `item.id`, i need to filter the above collection based on `lineNumber` and `item.id` and i need to project only selected fields.

Expected output below:

```
{
  "_id": "1",
  "lines": [
    {
      "lineNumber": "1",
      "item": {
        "id": "BAT10001",
        "name": "CricketBat",
        "description": "Cricket bat"
      },
      "quantity": 10
    }
  ]
}
```

**Note:** I may not get `lineNumber` all the times, if `lineNumber` is null then i should filter for `item.id` alone and get the above mentioned output.The main purpose is to reduce the number of fields in the output, as the collection is expected to hold huge number of fields.

I tried the below query,

```
db.sample.aggregate([
{ "$match" : { "_id" : "1"} ,
{ "$project" : { "lines" : { "$filter" : { "input" : "$lines" , "as" : "line" , "cond" : 
    { "$and" : [ { "$eq" : [ "$$line.lineNumber" , "3"]} , { "$eq" : [ "$$line.item.id" , "BAT10001"]}]}}}}}
])
```

But i got all the fields, i'm not able to exclude or include the required fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve it with [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) and [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) aggregation stages:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$match: {"_id": "1"}},
    {$unwind: "$lines"},
    {$match: {
        $or: [
            {"lines.lineNumber":{$exists: true, $eq: "1"}},
            {"item.id": "BAT10001"}
        ]
    }},
    {$group: {
        _id: "$_id",
        lines: { $push: {
            "lineNumber": "$lines.lineNumber",
            "item": "$lines.item",
            "quantity": "$lines.quantity"
        }}
    }}
])
```

- [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) - sets the criterias for the documents filter. The first stage is takes document with `_id` = "1", the second takes only documents which have `lines.lineNumber` equal to "1" or `item.id` equal to "BAT10001".
- [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) - splits the `lines` array into seperated documents.
- [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) - merges the documents by the `_id` element and puts the generated object with `lineNumber`, `item` and `quantity` elements into the `lines` array.

Comment: I tried the above query, it is not working for the lineNumber matching, it is bringing all the lineNumbers eventhough i provide the lineNumber as 1

Comment: Can you provide to me a sample data and your query which failed? Because the current query is working correctly with the sample data from the question. Or maybe I don't understand what you want :(

Comment: @vasantharajan I updated my answer, I hope it will helps to better understand what this query does.

Comment: find the output below,  {
    "_id" : "1",
    "lines" : [ 
        {
            "lineNumber" : "1",
            "item" : {
                "id" : "BAT10001"
            },
            "quantity" : 100
        }, 
        {
            "lineNumber" : "3",
            "item" : {
                "id" : "BAT10001"
            },
            "quantity" : 100
        }, 
        {
            "lineNumber" : "4",
            "item" : {
                "id" : "BAT10001"
            },
            "quantity" : 100
        }
    ]
}

Comment: My expected output is If i provide lineNumber and item.id then i need the record which is matching both the condition should come. So i changed your query to AND condition it worked fine for me.

Comment: The condition from your question: "I may not get lineNumber all the times, if lineNumber is null then i should filter for item.id alone and get the above mentioned output". This is unclear part :|

Comment: That's correct. But if i get both i should filter the data on 'AND' condition.

Comment: But `lines.lineNumber` is always exists in the document and your program just can search by both of them or only by `item.id`?

Comment: I will get lines.lineNumber and Item.id as a param for my method, Sometimes lines.lineNumber will be null, those times i will filter only based on item.id. If lines.lineNumber is available then i will filter on both the values.

Answer (score 10):

I tried the below query and it worked for me,

```
db.Collection.aggregate([
{ $match: { _id: '1' } },
{
  $project: {
    lines: {
      $map: {
        input: {
          $filter: {
            input: '$lines',
            as: 'line',
            cond: {
              $and: [
                { $eq: ['$$line.lineNumber', '3'] },
                { $eq: ['$$line.item.id', 'BAT10001'] },
              ],
            },
          },
        },
        as: 'line',
        in: {
          lineNumber: '$$line.lineNumber',
          item: '$$line.item',
          quantity: '$$line.quantity',
        },
      },
    },
  },
},
```

])